# Maven Jacoco - merge all test results in 1 overview

Tags: maven, jacoco-maven-plugin

Question: how can I merge the code coverage results of both the unit and integration tests in 1 Jacoco overview?

I have created all plugins.

Do I need to run the unit test first, and then the integration test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merging unit- and integration tests should not be merged. They have different goals.

If you would like to merge unittests, then you could look at the following simple demo project.

- Multi module project
- Unit test (via mvn clean install)
- Integration test (via mvn clean install -P integration-test)
- Jacoco - test coverage ( both aggregate datafile and aggregate reporting)
- FindBugs - code quality

Enjoy the [sipmle demo project](https://github.com/johan974/maven-multi-module-unittest-integrationtest-jacoco.git).